# extracting javascript code from html

Tags: regex

i would want to extract the id of this statement , how could i proceed with this in python. 
i am a beginner in python.

javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ibtnFind')

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re

input = """
javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ibtnFind')
javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ibtnFind2')
"""

m = re.findall("javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton\(event, '([^']+)'\)", input)

print m
```